# Chrome Packaged App: Take Screenshot / Display

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

Everyone

I need to take a screenshot in my app. It needs to include the entire screen, not just the browser (in windows - the start menu & tray; in iOS - the dock, menu bar).

Is there a way to do this in a packaged app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This would have been possible in the old Packaged apps because they allowed untrusted plugins to be installed, however in the new version of Chrome Apps this would not be allowed and is not available via any API.